# How to rotate a servo continuously?

Tags: arduino

I'm new in robotics. I bought a mini robot ( [Link](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2150619.pdf) ), which i rebuilt a little. Now it has legs and arms. This little robot has 4 little servos ([Link](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/3861-rs001a-dagu-micro-servomotor-8g-1-5kg-cm.html)). There are two wheels attached to two of these servos. I'd like to spin them, so the robot will "roll", but unfortinatly it is trickier than i tought.
The servos can rotate in 360 degrees(i can manually turn them), no problem with that. The problem is, that no matter how i try, the servo will turn only 180 degrees. So obviously i am making something wrong. 
If i write `myServo.write(0)` the servo rotates 180 degrees, and if i write `myServo.write(180)`, the servo rotates 180 degrees but in the other direction. How can i make it spin in only one direcvtion(360 degrees, more than 360 degrees)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question seems better suited for http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidCorbin: thanks, sorry i didn't know, that such a sackexchange does exist. I asked my question there.